# How can I write a recursive permutation function without using arrays and substrings in Java

Tags: java, recursion

My teacher and I were discussing whether or not a recursive permutation function could be written without the use of substrings and/or arrays in Java.

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Probably not with String since it is immutable. Maybe StringBuilder.

Comment: Without even a method signature, it's hard for us to know what we have to work with.  So what are the actual specifications/constraints involved?  What have you tried?

Comment: Permutation somehow also means you need a data structure to hold a sequence of elements. You could use a `List` but that is conceptually not so far from an array.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is yes, this can be done.  I'm assuming that "without the use of substrings and/or arrays" refers to the info being passed to the recursion.  You *have* to have some sort of container for the elements that are to be permuted.

In that case it can be done by pulling some hideous tricks with numerically encoding the indices of the elements as digits of a numeric argument.  For instance, if there are 3 elements and I use 1 as a sentinel value in the left-most digit (so you can have 0 as the leading index sometimes), 1 means I haven't started, 10 means the first element has been selected, 102 means the first and third, and 1021 means I'm ready to print the permutation since I now have a 4 digit argument and there are 3 elements in the set.  I can then deconstruct which elements to print using `% 10` and `/ 10` arithmetic to pick them off.

I implemented this in Ruby rather than Java, and I'm not going to share the actual code because it's too horrible to contemplate.  However, it works recursively with only the input array of elements and an integer as arguments, no partial solution substrings or arrays.